# Stdin in C or C++: Spotify: Reverse Binary Puzzle

Tags: c++, c, stdin

This is my first post on stack overflow so I apologize in advance if I miss a rule.
I tried to search a few posts however couldn't find what I was looking for.

I am trying to submit the [Reversed Binary problem](https://www.spotify.com/uk/jobs/tech/reversed-binary/) on Spotify however it is giving a reply "WRONG ANSWER". I have coded the problem in both C and C++, and I am able to validate answers for a lot of inputs. It doesn't seem that the problem is with the logic of the program. The puzzle states that "Input is read from stdin".

I have tried to use:

1. C: printf, scanf functions
2. C++: cout and cin functions (and writing "using namespace std" at the top)
3. C++: directly using std::cout and std::cin functions.

However none seems to work.

```
int stack[32];
top=-1
long inputNum,outputNum=0;
cout<<"Enter a Number\n";
cin>>inputNum;
while(inputNum>1) {
    if(inputNum%2 == 0) {
        push(0);
        inputNum=inputNum/2;
    } else if(inputNum%2 == 1) {
        push(1);
        inputNum=inputNum/2;
    }
}
push(1);
int i=0,x=0;
while(top>-1) {
    x=pop();
    if(x==0) {
        i++;
        continue;
    } else if(x==1) {
        outputNum=outputNum+powl(2,i);
        i++;
    }
}
cout<<outputNum;
```

Comment: Welcome! Please take a couple of minutes to read the [faq].

Comment: If you read the whole faq, you'll get a badge (c:

Comment: Post the shortest non-working example you can, maybe 20 lines of code. Explain what you were *expecting* to happen and what *actually* happened.

Comment: To format code on stack overflow, post it with a blank line before it and `    ` four leading spaces on each non-empty line.  You can also make `code snippets` by putting text in "backquotes" (right under the ~ key).  Code snippets is the easiest way to get `<` and `>` to show up as well.

Comment: int stack[32];    top=-1    long inputNum,outputNum=0;    cout<<"Enter a Number\n";  cin>>inputNum;  while(inputNum>1)  {  if(inputNum%2 == 0)
{  push(0);  inputNum=inputNum/2;  }  else if(inputNum%2 == 1)  {  push(1);  inputNum=inputNum/2;  }  }  push(1);  int i=0,x=0;  while(top>-1)  {  x=pop();  if(x==0)  {  i++;  continue;  }  else if(x==1)  {  outputNum=outputNum+powl(2,i);  i++;  }  }  cout<<outputNum;

Comment: My implementation is using stack so I ll just paste the logic excluding the standard stack push() and pop() functions.              I am sorry for the messy code, I tried to put 2 spaces for line break but it's not working (Even tried with 4 leading spaces). Can I attach or mail the .C or .Cpp file somewhere ? Also like I mentioned the code is running fine and I have tried it on a lot of inputs, and it gives the correct result. However when I submit it to Spotify I get an auto-generated mail "WRONG ANSWER". I feel it has something to do with "INPUT IS READ FROM STDIN"

Comment: The request for input, `"Enter a Number\n"` will be seen as output by spotify. All they want is for you to output a single number, nothing more nothing less. All you will get from `cin` is a single number, too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. You have to realise is that spotify thing seems to be an automated bot which compiles and runs your submitted code.

So first off you're polluting the answer by providing your "Enter A Number" prompt.  A bot wouldn't separate that from the real answer.

Secondly, I can't see how it compiles.  What's this **push()**, **pop()**, **top** and **stack** code?  Are you trying to use std::stack class?  If so, check how you're using it.

On the other hand, if you're not using std::stack, but some of your own custom macros (not shown), then my bet would be to check those.

Comment: Yes, I realize its an automated not. Let me remove the cout statements, and just print (cout) the final answer in the last and try again.  Due to lack of space I did not copy the entire code. I implemented stack push() and pop() functions, their definitions are just below my main(). Top is a variable that keep tracks of stack current position which starts with -1, the first push will be at stack[++top] which is stack[0]. Stack[32] is an integer stack of 32 elements as the largest number I need is 1 billion which can be contained by any data type which is 32 bit long(Log 2 1000000000)= 32 Bits.

Comment: Okay ... I think the first COUT Statement was the problem, I removed the "cout<<"Enter a number\n"" and now it is accepting my solution. THANK YOU GUYS !

Comment: This is what I was trying to highlight in my answer, you need to test and check that the output is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To read from stdin in c++, and write to stdout:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    std::cout << reverse_binary(value);
}
```

You just need to implement `reverse_binary` (c:

You can extract this to a function which works with any streams:

```
void main_io(std::istream& input, std::ostream& ouput) {
    unsigned int value;
    input >> value;
    output << reverse_binary(value);
}
```

And call it using `cin` and `cout`:

```
int main() {
    main_io(std::cin, std::cout);
}
```

Or you can test it using `stringstream`s:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::istringstream input("13");
    std::ostringstream output;

    main_io(input, output);

    assert(output.str() == "11");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your streaming (though buggy) works fine.
I ran you code with,

```
int reverse_binary(int value)
{
  if (value == 13) return 11;
  return 1;
}
```

It must be within your own reverse_binary function.
What's your actual problem?

Comment: The problem is when I send this solution (Which works perfect on my IDE Xcode for any number 1<=n<=1000000000) to Spotify Mail group "puzzle@spotify.com", I receive this response:                     <br/> Hello Shishir Mahajan,
Thank you for submitting a solution to our problem "reversebinary"!
We have tested your solution, and while doing so we unfortunately
discovered the following error:
Wrong Answer But don't let this discourage you, feel free to fix your program and
try again! Yours truly, Spotify

Comment: I am not able to figure out, what to correct as I don't see the problem in the solution.